# Project Euler # 20 factorial digit sum in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> n! means n × (n − 1) × ... × 3 × 2 × 1
>
> For example, 10! = 10 × 9 × ... × 3 × 2 × 1 = 3628800,
> and the sum of the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27. Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!

```
def fact(n):
    """returns factorial of n."""
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)


def count_digits(n):
    """Assumes n > 1.
    returns sum of digits of n's factorial."""
    factorial = fact(n)
    total = 0
    for digit in str(factorial):
        total += int(digit)
    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_digits(100))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standardlibrary module `math` already contains a `factorial` function. On my machine it is about 20 times faster than your function using `n = 100`. It also does not suffer from stack size limitations as yours does (try computing `fact(3000)`).

Alternatively you could learn about memoizing, which will help you in many Project Euler problems. Here it would be useful if you had to evaluate the factorial of many numbers (and even better if the numbers are increasing).

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    cache = func.__cache = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = args, frozenset(kwargs.items())
        if key in cache:
            ret = cache[key]
        else:
            ret = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
    return wrapper


@memoize
def fact(n):
    ...
```

Note that this decorator only works if your arguments are hashable (so no lists for example).

---

Since getting the sum of the digits of a number is something you will regularly need for Project Euler problems, you should make it a function on its own, which you put in a `utils` module, to be reused later:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    """Return the sum of the digits of `n`"""
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))
```

This will also be faster than your manual `for` loop or a list comprehension. Not by much, but it is measurable for very large numbers:

```
def digit_sum_list_comprehension(n):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(n))

def digit_sum_for(n):
    total = 0
    for digit in str(n):
        total += int(digit)
    return total
```

[image]

Comment: Bit odd to say "don't reinvent math.factorial" and then reinvent functools.lru_cache :-P

Comment: @Manuel You are absolutely right. But in my excuse, I was still stuck having to use Python 2 at the time, which does not have `lru_cache`, as it was only introduced in Python 3.2 (albeit in 2011).

Comment: Your "list_comprehension" solution doesn't have a list comprehension.

Comment: @KellyBundle You are right, it is actually a generator expression...

Answer (score 1):

For even more speed than Graipher's solution, we can count the digits and multiply instead of turning every single one into an `int`:

```
def digit_sum_count(n):
    count = str(n).count
    return sum(i * count(str(i)) for i in range(1, 10))
```

Benchmark with Graipher's three versions and mine on n=3333! (which has 10297 digits):

```
2.75 ms  2.75 ms  2.73 ms  digit_sum
3.22 ms  3.18 ms  3.20 ms  digit_sum_list_comprehension
3.31 ms  3.31 ms  3.32 ms  digit_sum_for
1.73 ms  1.72 ms  1.74 ms  digit_sum_count
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from math import factorial

def digit_sum(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))

def digit_sum_list_comprehension(n):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(n))

def digit_sum_for(n):
    total = 0
    for digit in str(n):
        total += int(digit)
    return total

def digit_sum_count(n):
    count = str(n).count
    return sum(i * count(str(i)) for i in range(1, 10))

funcs = [
    digit_sum,
    digit_sum_list_comprehension,
    digit_sum_for,
    digit_sum_count,
]

n = factorial(3333)
print(len(str(n)))
number = 10

# Correctness
expect = funcs[0](n)
for func in funcs:
    print(func(n) == expect, func.__name__)
print()

# Speed
tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(3):
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(n), number=number)) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in ts), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Now I would be curious to see how using a `collections.Counter` would fare, since it only needs one pass on the string instead of ten. Would also be interesting to see when, if ever, your approach becomes slower than mine.

Comment: @Graipher You mean you'd like to see whether `Counter` would slow it down so much that it'd be slower than yours? And I guess if you make `n` *small* enough, yours might eventually be faster. Oh and I'm not doing ten passes, I'm doing nine.

Comment: I will test it later and then I'll see.

Comment: You are right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCjMT.png
This is with the `str(n)` taken out and directly passing a string to the functions, since at ~10^5 digits that seems to start dominating the results.

Comment: Thanks for plotting. Btw I also tried mine with `count = str(n).replace('0', '').count`. That's another pass, but for n=3333!, about 17% of the digits are zeros and thus the nine counting passes have 17% less to do. But it was slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

100! ends with 24 zeros.  You can save carrying those around unnecessarily.  With a bit of thought, we don't need to remove them every iteration, because zeros only appear when we multiply by a number containing 5 in its factorisation:

```
def factorial_no_trailing_0s(n):
    """Factorial of n, with trailing zeros removed."""
    fact = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        fact *= i
        if i % 5 == 0:
            while fact % 10 == 0:
                fact //= 10
    return fact
```

or, probably more efficient (but I haven't benchmarked):

```
def factorial_no_trailing_0s(n):
    """Factorial of n, with trailing zeros removed."""
    fact = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        while i % 5 == 0:
            i //= 5
            fact //= 2
        fact *= i
    return fact
```

Comment: Actually, 100! ends with *24* zeros. Interesting idea, though benchmarks would be good to see whether / how much faster these are / make it.

Comment: I didn't count - I just reckoned 25 from 5,10,15,... and 4 more from 25,50,75,100.  Ah, I see what I did - that first batch is only 20 elements!